# Can a Ruby method accept a 2D array as parameters?

Tags: ruby

Say I wanted to pass an array like this:

```
[['Person1', '14'], ['Person2', '26']]
```

To a method, how would I do that?

I tried:

```
def people([person1, age1], [person2, age2])
```

But that threw an error.

Thoughts?

Edit1: Here is my actual code, and the error message it is generating:

```
def who_wins?(*game)
    if (game[0][1] =~ /[r]/i && game[1][1] =~ /[s]/i) || (game[0][1] =~ /[s]/i && game[1][1] =~ /[p]/i) || (game[0][1] =~ /[p]/i && game[1][1] =~ /[r]/i)
        return game[0][0]
    elsif (game[0][1] =~ /[r]/i && game[1][1] =~ /[p]/i) || (game[0][1] =~ /[s]/i && game[1][1] =~ /[r]/i) || (game[0][1] =~ /[p]/i && game[1][1] =~ /[s]/i)
        return game[1][0]
    elsif game[0][1] == game[1][1]
        return game[0][0]
    elsif
        raise NoSuchStrategyError.new
    end
end
```

When I declare a 2d array like this:

```
g = [["Marc", "R"], ["Sandy", "S"]]
```

and I pass it to the method like:

```
who_wins?(g)
```

I am getting this error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
```

Comment: The question is not clear. Do you want to directly access the variables inside the arrays?

Comment: if you just want to pass to a method, what is def ?

Comment: @sawa yes, I do want to access the variables inside the arrays. So I would like to be able to say check to see if person1 age is 14, and if it is...then return `X`. If not, then do something with person2, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def people(((person1, age1), (person2, age2)))
 puts "Person1 is #{person1}"
 puts "Age1 is #{age1}"
 puts "Person2 is #{person2}"
 puts "Age2 is #{age2}"
end

people([['Person1', '14'], ['Person2', '26']])
# => "Person1 is Person1"
# => "Age1 is 14"
# => "Person2 is Person2"
# => "Age2 is 26"
```

**Edit**

```
def who_wins?(game)
    if (game[0][1] =~ /[r]/i && game[1][1] =~ /[s]/i) || (game[0][1] =~ /[s]/i && game[1][1] =~ /[p]/i) || (game[0][1] =~ /[p]/i && game[1][1] =~ /[r]/i)
        return game[0][0]
    elsif (game[0][1] =~ /[r]/i && game[1][1] =~ /[p]/i) || (game[0][1] =~ /[s]/i && game[1][1] =~ /[r]/i) || (game[0][1] =~ /[p]/i && game[1][1] =~ /[s]/i)
        return game[1][0]
    elsif game[0][1] == game[1][1]
        return game[0][0]
    elsif
        raise NoSuchStrategyError.new
    end
end

p who_wins?([["Marc", "R"], ["Sandy", "S"]]) # => "Marc"
```

**Edit2**
By the way, your code can be refactored like this:

```
def who_wins?(game)
    case game.map{|_, tactics| tactics.downcase}
    when %w[r p], %w[s r], %w[p s]
      game[1][0]
    when %w[r s], %w[s p], %w[p r], %w[r r], %w[s s], %w[p p]
      game[0][0]
    else
      NoSuchStrategyError.new
    end
end
```

Comment: While I like this solution, I prefer the more elegant `(*array)`. I have updated the question with my exact code and the error I am seeing now. Thoughts on how I can resolve that?

Comment: @marcamillion In that case, you do not need `*` or do any other special thing. See my answer.

Comment: Except that your refactor isn't case insensitive...or is it?

Comment: @marcamillion There were some mistakes in my refactor. Now it is fixed.

Comment: Why did you use `_` as the first element of that block? I don't get it.

Comment: It is a conventional way to indicate an argument that is not used. The case statement only needs the "R", "S", "P" part. So `_` is used to indicate that were are throwing out the player part, creating an array just with the "R", "S", "P" part. In this particular case, it will be `["R", "S"]`. Then, `map` and `downcase` changes it to `["r", "s"]`, and that can be compared to the pairs given in the case statement.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for the education :)

Answer (score 2):

Change your method definition like this: `def who_wins?(game)` instead of, `def who_wins?(*game)`

You are using Splat Operator which is not required in your case.

If you want to learn more about Ruby Splat Operator, then click [here](http://4loc.wordpress.com/2009/01/16/the-splat-operator-in-ruby/)

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a variable argument list.

```
def people(*arrays)
  puts arrays.length
end
```

That is, if you wanted to pass in the people as you specified. Otherwise you'd just use a single argument like:

```
def people(arrayOfArrays)
  puts arrayOfArrays.length
end

people([['Person1', '14'], ['Person2', '26']])
```

Comment: How would I access the elements within the arrays inside the method?
E.g. say I wanted to `puts Person1 of age 14`...how might I go about doing that?

Comment: puts arrayOfArrays[0][0] + "of age " + arrayOfArrays[0][1]

Comment: So I like this, but I am getting a `NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass`. I put my code and the full explanation of what I am doing in the question. Refresh and let me know your thoughts...if you can. Thanks.

Comment: Your mixing the two styles of method declaration. When you declare the argument as a vararg using * def who_wins?(*game) it assumes the argument is an array. To use the g = [["Marc", "R"], ["Sandy", "S"]] syntax you'll have to remove the *. for example def who_wins?(game)

Comment: If you like the vararg solution, you need to call it with two separate arrays instead of one 2d array. who_wins?(["Marc", "R"], ["Sandy", "S"])

Comment: Thanks...I chose the non-vararg way.

Answer (score 1):

```
def who_wins?(game)
 #....
end

print who_wins([['Person1', 's'], ['Person2', 'r']])

# Output #
# ['Person2', 'r']
```

This is working for me.

Comment: That doesn't work for me. I get the same error when I try running that.

Comment: then you are doing something else wrong. this is how you pass array as an argument.

Answer (score 0):

It would be just

```
def people(twoDArray)
```

and then you could do things like

```
twoDArray[0][1]
```

Comment: I tried this, but then I get an argument error:
`ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)`

Comment: I have updated the question with my actual code and the error I am getting. Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Passing a 2D array to this method worked for me like this:

```
def method_name(arr=Array.new(size){Array.new(size)})

end
```